# NPE on finishAffinity android 5.0

Tags: android, kotlin

I got NPE for code

```
finishAffinity ()
```

I know that code was only introduced in API 16, but I got `npe` on API 21
Should I used

```
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this) ?
```

I code in kotlin

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: Post the error log

Comment: there is some other code in your activity, that goes null when you call this method.
paste your activity code

Comment: post your splash activity code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value

You can use **`try-catch`** block

```
  try {
        ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this@YourActivityName)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        finish()
    }
```

Note- If same problem coming then share minimum code.